# Error: void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Buen dia, por favor su apoyo con este codigo que intento correr pero me arroja error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference**

```
package com.example.strongapp.Activities;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.example.strongapp.Activities.Principales.Contenedor;
import com.example.strongapp.R;
import com.example.strongapp.clases.CustomPagerAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class Program extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


 TextView LunesG, MartesG, MiercolesG, JuevesG, ViernesG;

 FirebaseFirestore mFire;








@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);




    mFire = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.ViewPagerProgram);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext()));


    LunesG =new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    MartesG =new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    MiercolesG = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    JuevesG =new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    ViernesG = new TextView(getApplicationContext());













    VerProgram();





}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {










}



public void VerProgram() {

    mFire.collection("Program").document("Dias").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            String Lunes = documentSnapshot.getString("Lunes");
            LunesG = findViewById(R.id.LunesGrande);
            LunesG.setText(Lunes);

            String Martes = documentSnapshot.getString("Martes");
            MartesG = findViewById(R.id.MartesGrande);
            MartesG.setText(Martes);

            String Miercoles = documentSnapshot.getString("Miercoles");
            MiercolesG = findViewById(R.id.MiercolesGrade);
            MiercolesG.setText(Miercoles);









        }
    });

}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    startActivity(new Intent(this, Contenedor.class));
    finish();

  }


}
```

Observo que el ID del text view en el xml esta bien escrito:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Fragments.Miercoles">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/MiercolesGrade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048"
    android:text="@string/Miercoles"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Estos Son Los Fragments Anterioes:

El Primero

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Fragments.Lunes">



 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/LunesGrande"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048"
    android:text="@string/Lunes"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

El segundo:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Fragments.Miercoles">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MiercolesGrade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048"
    android:text="@string/Miercoles"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Aqui esta el Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.strongapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Skills"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Plan" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Videos" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Perfil" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Program" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Principales.Splash"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Principales.Registro" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Principales.IniciarSesion"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Principales.Contenedor" />
 </application>
```

Aqui esta el ModelObject:

```
package com.example.strongapp.clases;


import com.example.strongapp.R;

public enum ModelObject  {

Lunes(R.string.Lunes, R.layout.fragment_lunes),
Martes(R.string.Martes, R.layout.fragment_martes),
Miercoles(R.string.Miercoles, R.layout.fragment_miercoles);


private int mTitleResId;
private int mLayoutResId;

ModelObject (int titleResId, int layoutResId){
  mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
  mTitleResId = titleResId;

}

public int getmTitleResId() {
    return mTitleResId; 
}


public int getmLayoutResId() {
    return mLayoutResId;
}


}
```

Trato de Enviar las variables con los fragments en ViewPager en los Fragments anteriores funciona perfectamente pero cuando intento con el tercero sale ese error.

Comment: No veo ningún `TextView` en el XML que tenga el id `MartesGrande`, por lo que esto está resultando en un NPE: `MartesG = findViewById(R.id.MartesGrande);`

Answer (score 0):

El error se genera generalmente porque en tu layout no se tiene el `TextView` del cual intentas obtener la referencia, en este caso no existe el `TextView` con id `MartesGrande`, el elemento debe existir, de otra forma marcara el error comentado al llamar `setText()` :

```
        String Martes = documentSnapshot.getString("Martes");
        MartesG = findViewById(R.id.MartesGrande);
        MartesG.setText(Martes);
```

**En este caso el problema es que tienes un pager en donde se están agregando los Fragments, recuerda que estos pueden no estar construidos o pueden estar destruidos por lo tanto no encontraras la referencia, te sugiero validar**:

```
        String Lunes = documentSnapshot.getString("Lunes");
        LunesG = findViewById(R.id.LunesGrande);
        if(LunesG!= null){
           LunesG.setText(Lunes);
        }

        String Martes = documentSnapshot.getString("Martes");
        MartesG = findViewById(R.id.MartesGrande);
        if(MartesG!= null){
           MartesG.setText(Martes);
        }

        String Miercoles = documentSnapshot.getString("Miercoles");
        MiercolesG = findViewById(R.id.MiercolesGrade);
        if(MiercolesG != null){
           MiercolesG.setText(Miercoles);
        }
```